# How to ensure that only one instance of embeddable object can be created in a JPA entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to generate JPA classes for legacy RDMS project.

There is an entity class **Person**, written in JPA.
The entity **Person** has another **Embeddale** class called **Address**.

I can use **set**, **list** or **map** mapping for Embeddable **Address**. With any of these there can be multiple embedded objects in **Person**.

But the requirement is - *there can be at most only one instance of embeddable object. How to achieve this requirement? I cannot use subclass entities, it has to be embeddable object only.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use single value association something like below

```
    @Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
  private Address address;
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
  private String street;
  private String city;
}
```

You can read more about @oneToOne [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)

Comment: Thanks, What is @JoinColumn(name = "address_id") mean ? Does it mean that Address will have its own table ?

Answer (score -1):

Using **@Embedded** annotation the columns of **@Embeddable** class will be mapped to parent entity's table and hence will have only one instance.